# JXTreeTable: how to use ComponentProvider to set the renderer for one column

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jtreetable

I'm using JXTreeTable to display some data and I want to use the provided mechanisms of SwingX to change the renderer for some columns.

I previously used a JXTable and custom implementations of TableCellRenderer but this doesn't work anymore (I see strings where I should have progress bars, buttons,...).

I thus tried to achieve what I want by doing:

```
examsTable.getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableRenderer(new ButtonProvider()));
```

But the overriden method `createRenderer` of ComponentProvider is called once (even when I have more than one line in my JXTreeTable) and no button is shown (the method only contains `return new JButton();`).

Thanks!

Edit> Hoped you would answer kleopatra and thus happy you did.

I did my best but somehow the table is not displayed. I guess I forgot something (I'm a C++ developer new to Java) but I guess it's not a serious problem and it's probably not related to my main problem.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.HighlighterFactory;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.CellContext;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.ComponentProvider;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.DefaultTableRenderer;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.AbstractTreeTableModel;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    JXTreeTable table = new JXTreeTable();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Test() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        table.setEditable(false);
        table.setDragEnabled(false);
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setHighlighters(HighlighterFactory.createAlternateStriping());
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        class Series {
            public String seriesInstanceUID;
            public String patientName;
            public String patientBirthDate;
            public String securityToken;

            public Series(String seriesInstanceUID, String patientName, String patientBirthDate, String securityToken) {
                this.seriesInstanceUID = seriesInstanceUID;
                this.patientName = patientName;
                this.patientBirthDate = patientBirthDate;
                this.securityToken = securityToken;
            }
        }

        class Study {
            public List<Series> series = new ArrayList<Series>();
        }

        class Root {
            public List<Study> studies = new ArrayList<Study>();
        }

        AbstractTreeTableModel model = new AbstractTreeTableModel() {
            Root root = new Root() {
                {
                    studies.add(new Study() {
                        {
                            series.add(new Series("Series 1.1", "Mr. X", "1988-10-23", "sec-xx-1"));
                            series.add(new Series("Series 1.2", "Mr. X", "1988-10-23", "sec-xx-2"));
                            series.add(new Series("Series 1.3", "Mr. X", "1988-10-23", "sec-xx-3"));
                        }
                    });
                    studies.add(new Study() {
                        {
                            series.add(new Series("Series 2.1", "Mrs. Y", "1960-02-11", "sec-yy-1"));
                        }
                    });
                    studies.add(new Study() {
                        {
                            series.add(new Series("Series 3.1", "HAL 9000", "1975-04-21", "sec-zz-1"));
                            series.add(new Series("Series 3.2", "HAL 9000", "1975-04-21", "sec-zz-2"));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {

                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return "Series Instance UID";

                case 1:
                    return "Patient Name";

                case 2:
                    return "Patient Birth Date";

                case 3:
                    return "View online";

                default:
                    return "";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
                if (parent == root) {
                    return root.studies.indexOf(child);
                }

                if (parent instanceof Study) {
                    Study study = (Study) parent;

                    return study.series.indexOf(child);
                }

                return -1;
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
                if (parent == root) {
                    return root.studies.size();
                }

                if (parent instanceof Study) {
                    Study study = (Study) parent;

                    return study.series.size();
                }

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
                if (parent == root) {
                    return root.studies.get(index);
                }

                if (parent instanceof Study) {
                    Study study = (Study) parent;

                    return study.series.get(index);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(Object node, int columnIndex) {
                if (!(node instanceof Series) && !(node instanceof Study))
                    return null;

                if (columnIndex < 0 || columnIndex >= getColumnCount())
                    return null;

                if (root == null)
                    return null;

                if (node instanceof Series) {
                    Series series = (Series) node;

                    if (columnIndex == 0)
                        return series.seriesInstanceUID;
                    else if (columnIndex == 1)
                        return series.patientName;
                    else if (columnIndex == 2)
                        return series.patientBirthDate;
                    else if (columnIndex == 3)
                        return series.securityToken;
                } else if (node instanceof Study) {
                    // Empty for now
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 4;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getRoot() {
                return root;
            }

            public void update() {
                modelSupport.fireNewRoot();
            }
        };

        table.setTreeTableModel(model);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableRenderer(new ComponentProvider<JButton>() {
            {
                rendererComponent.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
            }

            @Override
            protected void format(CellContext context) {
                rendererComponent.setText(getValueAsString(context));
            }

            @Override
            protected void configureState(CellContext context) {
                rendererComponent.setHorizontalAlignment(getHorizontalAlignment());
            }

            @Override
            protected JButton createRendererComponent() {
                return new JButton("View online");
            }
        }));

        panel.add(table);
        this.setContentPane(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Test()).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT>** I actually have observed that it works. But not the way I want. I want to see a real button (now it looks just a little bit different from the rest of the line), know the path to it (parent object and column index) and see effects when clicking or hovering on it (button should look pressed,...).

How do I achieve that?

Comment: should work the exact same way as in a J/X/Table, nothing special related to rendering in a JXTreeTable (except the hierarchical column). Please show a sscce so we can find the bug in your code :-)

Comment: Question updated. The table doesn't show up for some reason. I've been trying to solve it for about half an hour and still can't figure out why it isn't shown... But that should, hopefully, not be a problem for you. Thanks!

Comment: something is wrong with your model (it doesn't show up even in a plain tree) - too lazy to dig what exactly ;)

Comment: fixed it by overriding getRoot(). Hopefully you can help me now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button is used, it only appears not to be in some LAFs:-)

Technically, the reasons are

- the highlighter sets the button's background
- the default visuals (used by the provider) sets the border to the default as returned by the cellContext

In combination the button doesn't look like a button for Metal (while it is unchanged f.i. in Windows)

No satisfying solution, options are

- not use striping
- let the button have a dont-touch-my-background property, extend the ColorHighlighter to respect that and use that custom highlighter for striping (there's an example in the test package)

Comment: that's exactly what I found out. I'll try the second option that you propose. Thanks!

Comment: How can I know what button has been clicked (what tree path,...)?

Comment: same way as in a standard JTable :-) Read about editors in the online tutorial

Comment: Could you please provide a link to this tutorial. I have a really hard time finding documentation for the swingx library (I'm mostly looking at the sources with jarvana :/)? Thank you very much!

Comment: kleopatra > I've been trying all afternoon to solve this but couldn't. I have found out that calling fireNewRoot() removes the cell renderer and this is why it seemed that it wasn't used in my project. However, I am still not able to figure out on which button the user clicks...